# How to delete grafana dashboard using curl command?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I am trying to delete grafana dashboard using curl command, but it is not deleting, the below curl command I tried to delete the dashboard,

```sh
curl -XPOST -d '{"name":"mydashboard"}' http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below command,

```sh
curl -k -X DELETE -u admin:admin http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db/dashboardslug_name
```

where `dashboardslug_name` is the name while save the dashboard and not the dashboard title displaying in the web url.